# CSS/JS Image on-click change synchronized on multiple devices

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, raspberry-pi

I wanted to ask if it would be possible to do some script or css style for the fact that once I click on the image it will change to another. I found a lot like this, but I need it a little differently, I need to see the picture changed on one device when I click the picture on another device.

In the code I have an image type input and after clicking on the input I need to change the picture and remember the already changed value. So when I open the page on the new device, the image has already been changed.

```
  <form method="get"> 
    <input type="image" class="switch_img" src="switch_off.png" value="Zapnout" name="on1">               
  </form>
```

(The program works like switching off and on of LEDs. And I want the clicker to make the "animation" of the switch.)

I have the variables stored in the txt file in Raspberry, here is the part of the code that could theoretically be connected:

```
    $fileName = __DIR__.'/txt/led2.txt';

        if (!file_exists($fileName) || (file_get_contents($fileName) !== '1' && file_get_contents($fileName) !== '0')) {
            file_put_contents($fileName, '1');
        }

        if (isset($_GET['on2']) && file_get_contents($fileName) === '1') {
            shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 15 1");
            file_put_contents($fileName, '0');
        }

        else if (isset($_GET['on2']) && file_get_contents($fileName) === '0') {
            shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 15 0");
            file_put_contents($fileName, '1');
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonasLochmann, read his question. he need async operation. chang in one device should reflect in another device also.

Comment: Yes, it's possible; but quite *how* depends on which devices, and how they're associated. Can you add enough detail and information that we can see what you're doing?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's going to go purely through CSS, I think JS will also be needed. I do not know much so I ask.

Comment: What holds the current state of the switches, where are you getting it from, all im seeing is a HTML form. If you want perfect sync, use web sockets, if not use server sent events or just poll.. but you will still need set/get the current state from somewhere.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The value 1 and 0 are written into the txt file directly in Raspberry. So when there is 1 there would be one picture and if 0 would change to the other. That could help those variables.

Comment: Cool, then have a sidechannel which sets it 0 and 1 though ajax post, then just poll that file and update. either way you need js.. cant just be done with CSS.. also store as json if you can, then you can just use it directly, and store multiple switch states in a single file.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using Raspberry Pi, given the mention of 'Raspberry' in your previous comment; if I'm right it might be worth checking [raspberrypi.se] to see if it's a solved problem already (though it's not off-topic here).

Comment: @LawrenceCherone And do you have any suggestions, how to do it? As I said, I cant´t JS, so.. :D I put part of the code into the questions.

Comment: @David Thomas This is very specific problem I guess..

Answer (score 0):

Projects like Vue, Vuetify and Axios make it easy to build out what you want with straightforward syntax, in just a few lines of "javascript".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>
          <h4>My Switch/s</h4>

          <v-alert type="error" :value="error">
            {{ error }}
          </v-alert>

          <v-card v-for="(item, index) in switches" :key="index">
            <v-card-title primary-title>
              <div>
                <div class="headline"></div>
                <span class="grey--text">{{ item.name }}</span>
              </div>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-switch v-model="item.state" :label="item.state ? 'On' : 'Off'" color="success" hide-details @click="setState(item)"></v-switch>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: () => ({
        error: false,
        pollId: 0,
        switches: [{
            name: 'LED 1',
            state: false
          }
        ]
      }),
      beforeDestroy: function() {
        clearInterval(this.pollId);
      },
      mounted: function() {
        this.getState()
        this.poll()
      },
      methods: {
        poll() {
          clearInterval(this.pollId)
          this.pollId = setInterval(() => {
            this.getState()
          }, 2000)
        },
        async getState() {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get('/switch.php')
            this.switches = response.data
          } catch (error) {
            this.error = error
          }
        },
        async setState(item) {
          item.state = !item.state
          try {
            await axios.post('/switch.php', item)
          } catch (error) {
            this.error = error
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Then the PHP part (switch.php):

```
<?php
$switches = file_get_contents('switches.json');

// handle toggle
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // get json body
    $body = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    // toggle the switch
    shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 15 '.intval(!empty($body['state'])));

    // set its current state
    if (isset($switches[$body['name']])) {
        $switches[$body['name']]['state'] = $body['state'];
    } else {
        $switches[$body['name']] = $body;
    }

    // save
    file_put_contents('switches.json', json_encode($switches, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

    header('HTTP/1.1 204 No content');
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($switches);
}
```

Untested but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: And it is posible to make it without online libraries?

Comment: Yeah sure, but you'll need to learn native javascript. Basically, if you want a dynamic site which is not constantly refreshing, you need to use js of sorts.

Comment: tbh javascript doesn't get much easier then Vue.js.. its why all the cool kids use it ;p

Comment: I mean, I want offline script cos this site will by hosted on localhost and my Rasp wont be online all the time, so thats why I need oflline script.

Comment: Yeah all them libs you can host locally, you could even download the google fonts (or not use vuetify and use bulma or something else). Lots of CSS libs include switches https://wikiki.github.io/form/switch/ using images/inputs is not how its done in 2018.